# Environmental config files when using pyinstaller?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am working on packaging a series of Python scripts into a bundled EXE. The scripts are using the configparser module to handle SQL connection strings (among other things). I am looking for a way to create three versions of the EXE, one for each environment we elevate to. The only difference between each environment is the SQL server address.

I figured out how to include files, folders, etc. in the spec file and what I would like to do is call pyinstaller and feed it different SPEC files based off which environment I am building. Something like this for an integration SPEC file:

```
a = Analysis(['normalization_updater.py'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[
                ('*.py', '.'),
                ('resources/config_int.cfg', 'resources/config.cfg')
             ],
```

and for PROD:

```
a = Analysis(['normalization_updater.py'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[
                ('*.py', '.'),
                ('resources/config_prod.cfg', 'resources/config.cfg')
             ],
```

In other words, I want to rename the config file being bundled into the EXE based off which SPEC file is used via the glob pattern.

Or is there a better way to handle feature toggles with pyinstaller EXE's? Perhaps feeding it a command line switch? If I am reading this right [the docs](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html#giving-run-time-python-options) say that's not possible.

> You can pass command-line options to the Python interpreter. The interpreter takes a number of command-line options but only the following are supported for a bundled app:
>
> - v to write a message to stdout each time a module is initialized.
> - u for unbuffered stdio.
> - W and an option to change warning behavior: W ignore or W once or W error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure it is what you need but here how you can use a single spec file just changing a line in start

```
env='int'

a = Analysis(['normalization_updater.py'],
         binaries=[],
         datas=[
            ('*.py', '.'),
            ('resources/config_' + env + '.cfg', 'resources/config.cfg')
         ],
```